# Unable to loop the Excel data in Chrome using Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm finding difficulty in loop functionality, ie. taking the values from excel sheet and performing the task. I have this website: **http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp** wherein I need to input IEC Code:

1. 0906008051
2. 0906008069

**Later input the**

Shipping Bill no :

1. 3929815
2. 3953913
3. 3979509

I mean that for now I have hard coded but I'm not getting it to function in a loop since I have large data and I cannot write it in a hard code fashion, since for 1 IEC number I have around 1000 SB.no, so there can be 100 IEC numbers, hence many Shipping bills (SB.no) no's.

Working with the tabs I have solved but then working with multiple Shipping bills no.'s is causing me problems.

I could manage this much of a code :

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub multipletabtest()

Dim bot As WebDriver
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim count As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "Chrome"
'count = 1
'While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)

bot.Get "http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp"

bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='iec']").SendKeys "0906008051"
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").SendKeys "3929815"
bot.Wait 10000         'Time to enter the captcha

bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter          'Take the value from final result sheet
bot.SwitchToNextWindow

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text
'Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text  'To extract the data
'bot.Window.Close


bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").Clear

bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").SendKeys "3953913"
bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter
bot.SwitchToNextWindow

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text
'Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text


'count = count + 1
'Wend
bot.Quit
End Sub
```

And since if anyone is wondering why **Ctrl+Enter**, that's because the **Captcha** remains the same for other Shipping bill no., so chose this method.

I have tried the while statement as well, but then the extracted data is being copied twice.

[image: See image]

Comment: How are you determining the appropriate combinations of IEC and SB? Where are they stored?

Comment: Shipping bill no's are in excel sheet "Column B", 
IEC no. i guess can be hard coded or be in Column A throughout(each against column B's SB).

I have edited

This Way or we can hard code IEC no for the first 1000 SB's.
This is excruciating for me .

Comment: If you have them appropriately paired up in sheet as 2D array then read into array and just loop the array indexing into it to retrieve the IEC and SB to use in each loop iteration.  The big problem is likely to be about timings and ensuring required info is ready. Check if scraping allowed and perhaps reconsider, with appropriate pauses, using xhr GET and POST as will be much faster.

Comment: Sir i  have very little knowledge on those topics, for now i need to loop those values from excel to run this program.
I have been on this since yesterday and i'm not getting any further.

Comment: Use the same idea then. Have them paired appropriately in Col A and Col B (no gaps) and loop col A and read its value and use as IEC value and use OFFSET(0,1) to grab SB from col B. The real problem is going to be writing in tests/conditions to ensure steps have been successful e.g. data is ready to be copied.

Comment: Okay i'll start working on it right away.Thanks.

Comment: @QHarr Done Sir !
Made two columns of IEC and SB codes.
Ran them up in a while loop , and using " bot.Window.Close

bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow "  methods.
It is functional now.
Thanks for your time & patience.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub multipletabtest()

Dim bot As WebDriver
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim count As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "Chrome"
bot.Get "http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp"

count = 1
While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)


bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='iec']").SendKeys Range("A" & count)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='sno']").SendKeys Range("B" & count)

bot.Wait 10000         'Time to enter the Captcha


bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter
bot.SwitchToNextWindow


If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//tr[2]//td[7]").count > 0 Then
Range("C" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr[2]//td[7]").Text

If bot.FindElementsByXPath("//p[contains(text(),'No Data Found.....check the Input Parameters')]").count > 0 Then
Range("C" & count) = "No Data"


End If
End If
bot.Window.Close

bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").Clear


count = count + 1
Wend

bot.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr - Can anything happen to that line (Range("C" & count) = "No Data").
Basically this should should come when there's no data in "//tr[2]//td[7]"
But this code leaves it blank, which is fine but is there a way with which we can print our own comment ?

Comment: You've put a bounty. Is the original question/problem resolved by your answer above?

Comment: Is your last If failing then to identify? Is there a test case people can use ? i.e. an IEC and SB?

Comment: hahahha...my friend kept the bounty.
The original question is solved by my answer.
Apologies for the confusion.
Yes the "Last if" is failing to do so.

Comment: having you verified the xpath condition against the webpage?

Comment: yes the path is correct , that's why i get a blank when the data is not found in If conditions.
But i want something like "No data found" in the cells.
It's kind of opposite of sendkeys   (lol).

Comment: Please provide example test values that reproduce this problem and post it in a new question.

Comment: You can also consider accepting your answer above after 2 days.